# asp.net mvc controller method -> soap web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am quite familiar with ASP.NET MVC and know that a controller’s method can respond with XML and JSON apart from other things (i.e. behave like a restful webservice). I am just wondering whether I can make a controller method behave like a soap web service which responds with a SOAP XML response to a POST request? Maybe it is just question of responding with XML but this would be more like a restful web service. I want to avoid having to implement a separate web service project if possible. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Christian

Comment: well first of all, let me ask you this - *why* do you want to return SOAP? Is this for a specific client? Your internal code (JS/AJAX) should not work with SOAP (or even XML at all), you should deal with JSON.

Comment: unfortunately that's what the client wants. i would use json/restful myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement a separate web service project. All you need is to add a WCF service endpoint (.svc file) to your current web project. Also you are saying that you expect SOAP response after a GET request which of course doesn't make much sense because in the SOAP specification requests should be POST.

Comment: Darin could you please provide a link or something w.r.t. to the .svc bit? Thanks.

Comment: Right click on your web project, Add new Item, WCF Service. Visual Studio will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your thought is to create a single deployable MVC Web Application that can respond to both SOAP requests and RESTful requests (maybe even more?).  I have thought about this myself, however there is no point in re-inventing WCF as it can do both without any additional programming.  The ASP.Net MVC assemblies were not designed to function as a web service, and although it can, probably shouldn't be when other technologies exist that were designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Mmmh I have used controller methods as restful web services extensively to be consumed by ajax/jquery. MVC is highly extentable/changable so it should work ...

Comment: I have also used MVC to return Json/XML objects to AJAX calls (RESTful), but I think the additional overhead of attempting to recreate SOAP via MVC shouldn't be recommended, especially when WCF already exists.